# what is the figure for $f(x)=|\sqrt{x}|$

Tags: functions, radicals, absolute-value

**what is the figure of** $f(x)=|\sqrt{x}|$ ?
when I run y=abs(sqrt(x)) to matalab, i take this but I believe that is not the correct answer. Please give me a help:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhY2u.png)

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is always positive. Why absolute value sign for this? The graph of $y =\sqrt x$ is a parabola.

Comment: I use matlab R2015a

Comment: Maybe matlab thinks $\sqrt x $ can be a complex number, and $|\sqrt{-1}|=|i|=1$ and so on?

Comment: You want to calculate the principal square root, but it is not defined for negative values of x. What MatLab then does is described here: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sqrt.html    Did you mean $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ ?

Comment: No, I mean $f(x)=|\sqrt{x}|$ . But the matlab give me the same figure as $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to take the absolute value here, the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is always positive in the real space. Try typing the following code in to matlab and running it, it will produce the correct graph.

```
a = 10;
x =  linspace(0,a,1000); %creates a vector from 0 to a with 1000 discrete points
y =  sqrt(x);
plot(x,y);
```

However, to answer your question, If correctly inputted, matlab should produce exactly the same plot for $|\sqrt{x}|$ for that of $\sqrt{x}$. Perhaps you're doing something incorrectly. Try the following code -

```
a = 10;
x =  linspace(0,a,1000); %creates a vector from 0 to a with 1000 discrete points
y =  abs(sqrt(x));
plot(x,y);
```

and if that doesn't work, try this

```
a = 10;
x =  linspace(0,a,1000); %creates a vector from 0 to a with 1000 discrete points
h =  sqrt(x); y = abs(h);

plot(x,y);
```

Comment: Yes in maths is the same thing. But why if type y=sqrt(x) give me a different figure from the y=abs(sqrt(x))?

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look at that.

Comment: Ofcourse in that way works correctly but it is because you define yourself the domain of the sqrt() function. If you replace the linspace-command to include negative numbers ( eg. x =  linspace(-10,a,1000); ) , you ll take a different plot!!!

Comment: Of course you’ll take a different plot? You’re trying to plot a portion of the graph which is a complex number? You can’t plot complex numbers and real numbers on the same diagram, unless it’s on something like an Argand diagram.

Comment: Thank u for your help. Just now understand that it was the complex number plot.Thats my mistake!!!